# __doPostBack not setting IsPostBack = true

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have these two javascript functions, both executing __doPostBack.
The second one, for some reason, will execute the postback, but the IsPostBack variable is always false, unless I manually do the postback.

```
function ctlADUserLookup_Callback(name, email, department, company, office, loginname, mobile, telephone) {                    
    __doPostBack("Lookup_AddUser", name + "|" + loginname + "|" + email);
}

function ctlADGroupLookup_Callback(name) {            
    //__doPostBack("Lookup_AddADGroup", name);            
    form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = "Lookup_AddADGroup";
    form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = name;
    form1.submit();            
}
```

Any ideas? The functions are both called from identical script/controls.

Comment: Seen this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1361249.aspx?IsPostBack+False+after+calling+__doPostBack+ ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2460246/728795) also might be relevant